# C++ / C #define macro calculation

Tags: c++, c, macros

Suppose I have

```
#define DETUNE1 sqrt(7)-sqrt(5)
#define DETUNE2 sqrt(11)-sqrt(7)
```

And I call these multiple times in my program.

Are DETUNE1 and DETUNE2 calculated **every** time it is called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are DETUNE1 and DETUNE2 calculated every time it is called?

*Very unlikely*.

Because you are calling `sqrt` with constants, most compilers would optimize the call to the `sqrt` functions and replace it with a constant value. GCC does that at `-O1`. So does clang. ([See live](https://godbolt.org/g/5J0zEu)).

In the general case, if you have a macro with `n` being a runtime value:

```
#define DETUNE1(n) (sqrt(n)-sqrt(n))
```

then after the textual replacement, *at least* one of the `sqrt` functions will need to calculated.

Notice that your macro is *not* safe. You should have brackets around it to be safe. For example, as `DETUNE1 * DETUNE1` would not produce what you expect.

Comment: Thanks.Didn't know that .Is every function that is called with constants replaced in this way  ?

Comment: It's not *guaranteed* for every library function called with constants but most compilers will do constant calculations at compile time whenever possible.

Comment: You bring up a good point that compilers are pretty smart and would usually optimize this; however, it's not a guarantee that it will be optimized. Since it's a straight text-replacement, the compiler could decide to optimize it in some cases and not optimize it in others.

Comment: I only found it weird that `gcc` is actually optimizing it even with `-O0`.

Comment: By the way, I don't think any compiler is able to figure out if an external library method is stochastic or deterministic, because it doesn't have access to its source code and therefore no understanding about what it does at all. This kind of optimization is probabably only possible with instructions that are part of the standard, and possibly with functions that are fully implemented within the contemplated source code.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** it will be calculated every time. Better you `#define` the calculated value. You need to also make sure that put these in brackets as it may give unexpected result.

e.g. If you are using in calculation as below :

```
int result = DETUNE1 * 4
```

then it will result in

```
int result = sqrt(7)-sqrt(5) * 4
```

So multiplication will be done before subtraction because of `operator precedence in C`

Answer (score 2):

#define textually replaces your macro declaration so every time you write  :   DETUNE1 , sqrt(7)-sqrt(5) is placed in place of it.So if you write DETUNE1 multiple times multiple evaluations will be done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, a #define simply replaces every instance of the phrase with what you defined

When the compiler compiles your program, before it does any interpertation there is a stage called pre-processing. In this stage the compiler will blindly replace all #define instances with their definitions, so every place in your code that uses DETUNE1 will simply be replaced by sqrt(7)-sqrt(5) which is a calculation of course

You can use a variable to pre-cache this value, or better yet - calculate it yourself and store it in a define like so:

`sqrt(7)-sqrt(5) = 0.409`

So

`#define DETUNE1 0.409`

This is the most efficient way to do it - avoid calculations altogether.

See here for further information about C macros in gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros

Comment: only 3 digits? That's not much precision.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - yet another reason to avoid macros (as if we needed any more). Use `const`s instead:

```
const double DETUNE1 = sqrt(7) - sqrt(5);
const double DETUNE2 = sqrt(11) - sqrt(7);
```

Comment: There are a *lot* of reasons to use macros. There are many instances where they can be extremely useful, if not necessary, when writing in C/C++, even if they may not be the best choice in this scenario.

Comment: @pcluddite: I wouldn't say a *lot* of reasons - there are a certain number of specific cases where macros make sense, but in general they should be avoided for the vast majority of cases, such as defining constants (as is the case here), inline functions, etc, where much better alternatives exist.

Comment: I think one of the biggest benefits of using macros vs `const`s is the fact that macros *are* a straight text replacement. If you have a value that needs to be reused throughout your code, using a macro can forego needless memory allocation and ensure it won't be treated like any other type.

Comment: This won't work in C unless the const is declared at local scope.

Comment: @pcluddite: needless memory allocation - how so ?

Comment: @Lundin: true - it's one of those unfortunate "C/C++" questions.

Comment: @pcluddite Everything in a computer program has to be allocated _somewhere_. You cannot allocate constants in thin air. Whether a numeric constant is allocated in `.data` or in `.text` as part of the code itself shouldn't matter much, except the former will enable you to view it in a debugger.